# Pairing array elements in DIVs

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I have script that reads from a text file and inserts elements so that they may be styled and displayed. However, I now want to pair two elements inside a DIVs. Here is the code:

```
var lines = request.responseText.replace(/\r/g, "").split("\n");    // Remove carriage returns (\r) and place text into an array, split at the newline character (\n)
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {    // Cycle through each line in the array
            if (lines[i].length >= 57) {    // Check if the current line is lengthy, and if so.....separate function
            }
            var coup = document.createElement("div");    // Create a div element
            coup.id = "line" + i;    // Give the div an ID in the form of line0, line1, etc.
            coup.innerText = coup.textContent = lines[i];    // Place the current line of text in the div
            el_status.appendChild(coup);    // Append the div to the status box
        }
```

I would like line0 and line1 to go into one DIV. Then I would like line2 and line 3 to go into another DIV...

var coup does not have to be a div, I don't mind changing it to a p, span, or li.

Thanks!

Comment: Btw, obvious comments like `// Create a div element` are counterproductive.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lines = request.responseText.replace(/\r/g, "").split("\n");
for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i += 2) {
    var coup = document.createElement("div");
    coup.id = "line" + i;
    coup.textContent = lines[i - 1] + lines[i];

    el_status.appendChild(coup);
}​
```

Just iterate two each time, and place both in the same DIV, or some variation of that, depending on what structure you're after ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried your suggestion but it did not render correctly. The text file contains 9 lines but not all of them are going to be paired up.

Answer (score 1):

Basic way to try `document.createTextNode();` and adding two lines at every step of the iteration.

```
var lines = request.responseText.replace(/\r/g, "").split("\n");    // Remove carriage returns (\r) and place text into an array, split at the newline character (\n)
        for (var i = 0, l = lines.length; i < l; i += 2) {    // Cycle through each line in the array
            if (lines[i].length >= 57) {    // Check if the current line is lengthy, and if so.....separate function
            }
            var coup = document.createTextNode(lines[i-1] + lines[i]);    // Create a div element
            coup.id = "line" + i;    // Give the div an ID in the form of line0, line1, etc.
            coup.innerText = coup.textContent = lines[i];    // Place the current line of text in the div
            el_status.appendChild(coup);    // Append the div to the status box
        }
```

Also DOM manipulation is quite expensive and doing appends in a for loop may slow things down. So I'd rather do this:

```
var lines = request.responseText.replace(/\r/g, "").split("\n");    // Remove carriage returns (\r) and place text into an array, split at the newline character (\n)
var appendedLines = [];//create a new array.
        for (var i = 0, l = lines.length; i < l; i += 2) {    // Cycle through each line in the array
            if (lines[i].length >= 57) {    // Check if the current line is lengthy, and if so.....separate function
            }
            var coup = document.createTextNode(lines[i-1],lines[i]);    // Create a div element
            coup.id = "line" + i;    // Give the div an ID in the form of line0
            appendedLines.push(coup);   // Append the div to the status box
        }
el_status.appendChild(appendedLines.join(''));// this uses a single append statement.
```

Also, the point of `l = lines.length` is to further speed things up. When you use a for loop with a `i < someArray.length` condition, the JS interpreter will look for `someArray.length` at every single step of the iteration. storing a reference to `someArray.length` fixes that.

Comment: thanks for your input. I tried your suggestion but the it did not render correctly. Only the if statement work but the lines did not generate.